# Walking Dead App: Can't get out the pharmacy alive

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I am stuck in the pharmacy. No matter what decision I make, I die. If I save Carly I die. If I save Doug I die. Always the same way. They run, I try to save Clementine, she is saved, the father opens the door. I die every time, then he closes it. Game over. I've played at least seven times with the same result. I am so sick of seeing the same scene over and over. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after Larry punches you, Kenny returns and saves you. This happens regardless of your actions (but Kenny's dialogue and attitude change if you disagreed with him earlier).

You should not get a game over at this stage unless you're just reloading as soon as Larry hits you.